# CORS Issue - how to remove 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Response Header - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, express, cors

The backend API at http://example.ac.uk/sea/ is now proxied by an F5 device which automatically adds the CORS header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * to all responses. The gui code here appears to automatically add an CORS header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.ac.uk/sea/ where the value is set to whatever web page is doing the calling. So http://example.ac.uk for the production deployment but if deployed on a different server (e.g. http://example:81/data/sea/app/search) then the value changes (to http://example:81). This means that there are now two Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers in the response which makes browsers (tested in Chrome) refuse to load the data.

**Error:**

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://example.ac.uk/sea/dataTypes' from origin 'http://seas.example.test' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://seas.example.test, *', but only one is allowed.`

**These are my response headers:**

| Response Headers: |  |
| --- | --- |
| **Accept-Ranges:** | bytes |
| **Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:** | true |
| **Access-Control-Allow-Origin:** | http://seas.example.test |
| **Access-Control-Allow-Origin:** | * |

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is being added to the API response by the server it sits behind.

How do I, if possible, remove the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://seas.example.test` response-header?

Below is my proxy.js implementing express, used in the deployment process. I have tried to remove the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header but to no avail: `res.removeHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin');`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');
var app = express();

app.use(cors());

var proxyFromPath = '/api';

// get angular dev proxy details and re-use
var proxyConfig = require('../../proxy.conf.json');

var apiProxyConfig = proxyConfig[proxyFromPath];

// get proxy override
var proxyOverride = ''; // value replaced in dockerFile
if (proxyOverride === '') {
  proxyOverride = process.argv[2];
}

// if proxy override set, use it
if (proxyOverride) {
  apiProxyConfig.target = proxyOverride;
}
console.log(`proxy '${proxyFromPath}' => '${apiProxyConfig.target}'`);

app.use(
  proxyFromPath,
  proxy(apiProxyConfig),
);

// add root response message and link
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.removeHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin');
  res.send(`
  Successfully deployed.<br/><br/>
  Proxying from  '${proxyFromPath}' to '${apiProxyConfig.target}'<br/><br/><br/>
  Override this in the manual gitlab 'build_testing_proxy' job (on the master branch) by setting the 'PROXY_TO_URL' variable<br/><br/>
  Then don't forget to redeploy by running the 'deploy_testing_proxy' job<br/><br/><br/>
  API <a href="${proxyFromPath}">HERE</a><br/><br/>
  `)
});


app.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to allow cross origin requests in the server side. Ex:

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: ['http://seas.example.test']
}));
```

or you can add the wildcard like below and this should work with the proxy.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  next();
});
```

More on this [link](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-use-cors-in-nodejs-with-express/)

Comment: The response has multiple same headers. How would adding another header solve the problem? `The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://seas.example.test, *', but only one is allowed.` The OP already tried `app.use(cors());` and commented it out.